Finding UMVUE for Correlation Coefficient in Multivariate Normal Distribution

It is described in Wikipedia that: In statistics a minimum-variance unbiased estimator (MVUE) or uniformly minimum-variance unbiased estimator (UMVUE) is an unbiased estimator that has lower variance than any other unbiased estimator for all possible values of the parameter.

How to find the UMVUE of $\rho$, the correlation coefficient, for a single sample $X=\left(X_1,\cdots,X_n \right)$ from a population following a multivariate normal distribution $N\left(0,\Sigma_n\right)$, where the covariance matrix is：
$\Sigma_n=\sigma^2\,\left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & \rho & \cdots & \rho \\ \rho & 1 & \cdots & \rho \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ \rho & \rho &\cdots & 1\end{array} \right]\;,\;\rho \in \left(-1,1\right)$
The pair of statistics $\left(X'X, X'J_nX \right)$ forms a complete and sufficient statistic for the parameters $\left(\rho,\sigma^2\right)$, where $J_n$ represents a matrix of ones. Additionally, according to Cochran's theorem, the statistics $\hat{a_n} = X'(I-\frac{1}{n}J_n)X$ and $\hat{b_n} = X'J_nX$ are independent. Hence, I propose constructing the UMVUE $T(X)$ as the ratio $\frac{\hat{a_n}}{\hat{b_n}}$. However, calculating the expectation $\mathbb{E}\left[T\left(X\right)\right]$ presents a challenge. Could someone kindly assist me in computing this expectation, or alternatively, are there other methods available to derive the UMVUE of $\rho$?

You already posted this question recently. You could have edited the previous version instead of deleting it.
